# How shall I add one of the key and its values of second list of dictionary to the first list of dictionary based on the condition

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary-comprehension

From below lists, I want to add the 'Speed' from list_b to list_a if only 'Filename' of both lists matches.
My output of newly formed list_a need to have 4 keys now and their respective values.
How to do this?

first list of dictionary

```
list_a =[{'Filename': '20211004T102400622.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:00'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102400622.jpg'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102403688.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:03'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102403688.jpg'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102403684.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:03'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102403684.jpg'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102406737.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:06'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102406737.jpg'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102409773.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:09'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102409773.jpg'}]
```

second list of dictionary

```
list_b = [{'Filename': '20211004T102400622.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.3',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:00.622Z'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102403684.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.2',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:03.684Z'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102403688.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.2',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:03.688Z'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102406737.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.0',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:06.737Z'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102409773.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.1',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:09.773Z'}]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: I am a novice python learner, I have trouble in building the logic behind as I don't have experience in working with list of dictionaries of python

Comment: for i in list_a:
  for j in list_b:
    if i['Filename']==j['Filename']:
      list_a.insert(i['Speed'],j['Speed'])
      print(list_a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to create dictionary `filename_to_speed`, for looking up speed for a given filename. Then build the new list using a loop. First check in the filename exists in `filename_to_speed`, otherwise add a value `None`.

```
# I am guessing this is where Timestamp comes from.
# Or import it the same way you did in your code (not shown)
from pandas import Timestamp

list_a =[{'Filename': '20211004T102400622.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:00'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102400622.jpg'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102403688.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:03'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102403688.jpg'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102403684.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:03'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102403684.jpg'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102406737.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:06'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102406737.jpg'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102409773.jpg',
  'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:09'),
  'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102409773.jpg'}]


list_b = [{'Filename': '20211004T102400622.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.3',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:00.622Z'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102403684.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.2',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:03.684Z'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102403688.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.2',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:03.688Z'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102406737.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.0',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:06.737Z'},
 {'Filename': '20211004T102409773.jpg',
  'Speed': '0.1',
  'Time': '2021-10-04T10:24:09.773Z'}]


filename_to_speed = {dct['Filename'] : dct['Speed'] for dct in list_b}

list_new = []

for dct in list_a:
    if dct['Filename'] in filename_to_speed:
        dct['Speed'] = filename_to_speed[dct['Filename']]
    else:
        dct['Speed'] = None
    list_new.append(dct)

print(list_new)
# [{'Filename': '20211004T102400622.jpg', 'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:00'), 'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102400622.jpg', 'Speed': '0.3'}, {'Filename': '20211004T102403688.jpg', 'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:03'), 'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102403688.jpg', 'Speed': '0.2'}, {'Filename': '20211004T102403684.jpg', 'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:03'), 'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102403684.jpg', 'Speed': '0.2'}, {'Filename': '20211004T102406737.jpg', 'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:06'), 'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102406737.jpg', 'Speed': '0.0'}, {'Filename': '20211004T102409773.jpg', 'convertedDate': Timestamp('2021-10-04 10:24:09'), 'path_name': '/content/drive/My Drive/train later/Continuous Running Time/Front Camera/20211004T102409773.jpg', 'Speed': '0.1'}]
```

Comment: I am getting exactly what I wanted. Great!